# gRPC java spring server "error": "2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've created a simple test gRPC server(Java, Spring) to test the technology.

When trying to call a function from the server I am getting an error
{
"error": "2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed"
}

[image of error from blumRpc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysojm.png)

Inside the application, no stack trace is printed, I can't catch the program execution using breakpoint invisible for me code

```html
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example.grpc;

message LoginRequest{
  string login =1;
  string password =2;
}
message LoginResponse{
  string token = 1;
}

service LoginService{
  rpc login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse);
}
```

Here is my proto file

My pom XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>org.exampledriven</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-grpc-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <name>spring-boot-grpc-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lognet</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <!--Details here : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java-->
    
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>

            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                      The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
                      protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
                      protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
                    -->
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-lognet-maven</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/lognet/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-lognet-maven</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/lognet/maven</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My gRPC service

```html
@GRpcService
public class LoginServiceImpl extends LoginServiceGrpc.LoginServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public void login(com.example.grpc.LoginServiceOuterClass.LoginRequest loginRequest,
                      StreamObserver<LoginServiceOuterClass.LoginResponse> responseObserver){
        com.example.grpc.LoginServiceOuterClass.LoginResponse response = com.example.grpc.LoginServiceOuterClass.LoginResponse
                .newBuilder().setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
    }
}
```

All gRPC classes were successfully generated

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evdR2.png)

What can cause the problem? please help

Link to the project on GitHub for better analysis: https://github.com/Aretomko/SmartNews-project/tree/main/SmartNewsSever

Thank you in advance for your help))

Comment: You need add `responseObserver.onCompleted();` after `responseObserver.onNext(response);` to send response to client; And you can reference my code in [helloworlde/grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample) of how to use gRPC in Java

Comment: @HelloWood, thanks for your answer, It was a mistake but the problem was on the level of receiving the message, as I've posted in answer  I should provide different ports for the server and grpc service, after adding this configuration it started to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain the real root of the problem but the thing that helped me is providing different ports for the server and gRPC, hope it will help someone

```yaml
## Server Properties
server:
  port: 6789
  compression.enabled: true
  max-http-header-size: 20000

grpc:
  port: 6790
```